# Regex: To allow commas in excel file name

Tags: javascript, regex

I have JavaScript code that reads the content of an excel file.
The first step is to assign a regex to a variable of the name regex

```
 var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_!()\\.\-:])+(.xls|.xlsx)$/;
```

Then some programming occurs like:

```
if (regex.test($scope.SelectedFile.name.toLowerCase())) {
```

At times users submit excel files that in their names, they put commas, and that breaks the regex.

I would like to ask for help so that I can learn how to make this small modification to the current regex (that besides the issues with the commas, it has been working fine) without breaking it due to inexperience.

Any help is good.

Thank you,
Erasmo

Comment: That's a broken regex to begin with, because the dots where the extension is matched (`(.xls|.xlsx)`) need to be backslash escaped, or they match any character, not just a dot.

Comment: Thank you for your observation. Do you think you can help me correct that and also change it to allow commas?

Comment: What's needed first is a concise statement of what should be considered a valid or invalid file name, because as given, it allow crazy stuff, like tab characters, starting with a :, etc. For instance, if you allow commas, can a comma be the very first character?

Comment: The file name changes, because there is no naming convention at this moment in regards how the file name should be. I am trying to make the point to the powers that be, about the importance of this, but right now there is no answer. In the mean-time, I need to be able to accept files that have a coma anywhere in the name. Example: EDD - January 13, 2021 Agenda List.xlsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming the first character of the file name shouldn't be as flexible as the rest of the name, and fixing some other problems, the solution should look more like this:

```
var regex = /^[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9\x20_!()\.:,]*\.xlsx?$/i;
```

You don't have to do a-z and A-Z, or use that `toLowerCase()` in your code, if you simply put the `i` flag (for case-insensitive) at the end of the regex.

The space character (`\x20`) is now the only allowed whitespace. You can just type a space instead, but using plain spaces in regexes isn't always clear to a human reader of the code.

You don't need to test `xls` and `xlxs` seperately, because `xlsx?` makes the addition of one (and only one) `x` after `xls` optional.

If you want the file name to start with something other than a letter or a number, modify first character class.

I also removed unnecessary parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added the changes and will begin testing them. This is how the code reads now: 
var regex = /^[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9\x20_!()\.:,]*\.xlsx?$/i;
if (regex.test($scope.SelectedFile.name)) {

Comment: Does it look like I implemented it correctly? Especially the part in which the toLowerCase() is removed.